# Where is the correct place to build the needed Window for app in Cocoa macOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am confused to find the concert way for building the needed Window for app, so one of source say that I have to use this down code:

```
    import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    override func viewWillAppear() {
        

        self.view = NSHostingView(rootView: ContentView())

        self.view.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        self.view.window?.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
        self.view.window?.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
        self.view.window?.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.closeButton)?.isHidden = true

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

And some other source says I have use this code:

```
    @main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        
        let window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)

        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ContentView())
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        
        window.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
        window.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
        window.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
    }
    
    
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
    
    func applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(_ app: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    
}
```

Which I am really confused which one is needed and why? can some one explain it to me?

Comment: The code you posted seems to be related to whether your user interface code will be written in AppKit or SwiftUI.

Comment: @HangarRash: yes, how did you know?

Comment: The first one imports SwiftUI and used SwiftUI classes. The second is using AppKit classes.